# React-Slick Carousel - Disable arrows

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

We are using React-Slick for the Carousel effect in our application. The content in the slider is dynamic and the length of the Carousel items can be between 4 to 20.

The problem is that even when the width of all the content is less than the width of the slider track, the left-right arrows work.

[image: Carousel]

What is the solution/workaround to hide or disable these arrows in such case?

Comment: Don't they even get disabled? It would be great if you would provide your code, so we could reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 18):

Please take a look at their docs. They have an option disable it.

https://github.com/akiran/react-slick

```
<ReactSlick arrows={false}>...</ReactSlick>
```

Answer (score 15):

For disabling arrows you just need to add prop 'arrows' and set value 'false'

```js
 const settings = {
      infinite: true,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      arrows: false,
      className: 'notes-slider',
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 7000,
    };
```

- List item

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS along with JS, to modify the arrow visibility on the basis of data content.

I don't have the rep yet to post it as a comment, but that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
Below is my code and to disable arrows just make arrows as false in settings : 

class SimpleSlider extends React.Component {
 render() {
      var settings = {
      dots: true,
      autoplay: true,
      arrows: false
    };

    return (
      <Slider {...settings}>
            <div><img src='../../src/assets/1.jpg' /></div>
          <div><img src='../../src/assets/2.jpg' /></div>
          <div><img src='../../src/assets/3.jpg' /></div>
          <div><img src='../../src/assets/4.jpg' /></div>
        </Slider>
    );
}
}

Some more configurable properties can be found here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-slick
```

Answer (score 0):

Just arrows={false} example.

```
<Slider arrows={false}{...settings}>
            ...
</Slider>
```